# Need to show lookup columns as choice based on user

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have list like projects choice based on Person choice and I have another list where I need to show this Projects based on that person.

So Projects assigned to Person should be shown as choice.

Please help me achieve this.

Comment: Please try to extend your question with more details (and maybee images), it is very hard to understand what you are trying to achive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you have a list of projects where the project name and the person fields as columns. (Might be  project admin) Then you have another list where you need to lookup the projects assigned to that person.

You would be able to do such a customization if you are using SharePoint Designer with some customization. But I would prefer and of course you are not much good with SPD, get the item level permissions. Have a SP group where the admins are located (might be an existing one like Approvers or Members). Then always give them access to all list items in the project list. Then also assign read permissions to each person to each item where the user is mentioned in. This will be a solid, easy to deploy solution assuming the project list does not change frequently.